# How to bind a function with arguments into a package in C#

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics

I'm writing a thread pool use C#.

This thread pool needs to support execute different type of function.

Below is what I need:

1. bind a function and its arguments into a functor(or say callable object) and its signature should be void(void)
2. get a `System.Threading.Tasks< TResult >` that represents the return value of our callable package

In CPP, I can do it with some template magic:

```
template <typename funtype, typename ...argstype>
std::future<typename std::result_of<funtype(argstype...)>::type> async(funtype&& func, argstype&&... args) {
    //start function body↓

    typedef std::packaged_task<std::result_of<funtype(argstype...)>::type(argstype...)> task_type;
    auto task = std::make_shared<task_type>(std::forward<funtype>(func));

    // bind to a callable object(functor) with signature void(void)
    auto whatINeed= std::bind([task](argstype... args) mutable {
    (*task)(std::forward<argstype>(args)...);
    }, std::forward<argstype>(args)...);

    //and we return the std::future which represents the return value of our package
    //in C#, i need to return an Task<TResult>
    return task->get_future();
}
```

In C#, now I wrote:

```
public Task<TResult> async<TResult>(Delegate func, params object[] args)
{
    var stdPromiseXD = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
    // the lambda is a callable object with signature void(void)
    works.Enqueue(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            stdPromiseXD.SetResult((TResult)func.DynamicInvoke(args));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            stdPromiseXD.SetException(ex);
        }
    });
    // return the Task which equals std::future in CPP
    return stdPromiseXD.Task;
}
```

But this C# version is not good as CPP version. First its does not support non-return function, second the DynamicInvoke method could be significantly slow in some situation.

So can anyone tell me how to bind a function and arguments into a pack in C# more elegant?

Comment: My first question is probably why are you writing a thread pool yourself? Is there anything you can't do with the .Net Tasks? You might also think about doing "async all the way" as in: The delegates you pass in could be aware of the async pattern. (because cancellation is a cooperative task and it's handy to have the CancellationToken around to wait on it). Also you can just pass in function arguments before (higher order functions) & then just pass in the function with the captured arguments. The thread pool library doesn't do anything with the arguments, so it must not be aware of it,right?

Comment: To give a quick answer given the constraints: You probably need some overloads with generic arguments. (also the async usually goes before the return type in a function and your function doesn't have a name yet?)

Comment: @DennisKuypers just for fun, i know dotnet provide a thread pool for each program

Comment: @DennisKuypers overload....i know we can use overload, but i think that is not elegant. i want to use something beautiful like the template variable length parameter in C++11

Comment: I am not aware of any C# type-safe C++-variadic-style function mechanism. If you look this [action.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,7a86aba051da82dd) source you will also find various overloads and I assume that the authors of `Func` might have used something like this. (granted, they are delegates, not function declarations)

Comment: @DennisKuypers thank you very much !!! hope you have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `Func<TResult>` and `Action` instead of delegate and then using closures in the calling code to simplify the usage.  Func is a generic strongly typed delegate that returns a result and Action is a generic strongly typed delegate that doesn't return a result.

```
public Task<TResult> Enqueue<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
{
    var stdPromiseXD = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
    // the lambda is a callable object with signature void(void)
    works.Enqueue(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            stdPromiseXD.SetResult((TResult)func());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            stdPromiseXD.SetException(ex);
        }
    });
    // return the Task which equals std::future in CPP
    return stdPromiseXD.Task;
}

public Task Enqueue(Action action)
{
    return Enqueue<object>(() =>
    {
        action();
        return null;
    });
}
```

I called this with:

```
var arg1 = "x1";
var arg2 = "2nd";
var arg3 = "third";

var resultTask1 = tp.Enqueue(() => DoConsoleWrite(arg1, arg2, arg3));
var resultTask2 = tp.Enqueue(() => SumAllNumbers(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
var resultTask3 = tp.Enqueue(() => ThrowException());

while (tp.Pop()) { }

resultTask1.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var result2 = resultTask2.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var result3Exception = resultTask3.Exception;
```

The alternative to using closures is to create overloads for each parameter count of func (`Func<TResult>, Func<T1,TResult>, Func<T1,T2,Result>, etc` and and `Action, Action<T1>, Action<T1,T2>, etc`)

Comment: You are welcome.  If you consider this the answer to your question, please click on the checkmark to designate it as such.